# Dynamics NAV SQL Lead Time format conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I have a small issue getting data, one field in particular, from table replicated from Microsoft Dynamics NAV.

There is a field storing lead time in strange format and as a newbie I thought to ask smarter from me for advice.

There is a number followed by a character, which as I assume indicates "units".

[image: Example data]

What I got so far is character indicating days is used in row 2 & 4 and one for weeks is used in rows 1 & 3

Could someone tell is it some "standard" way of storing this kind of data?

Tell me how to convert those into days or point me in right direction?

I believe I found a solution, but it seems to be very ugly!

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT
  [ItmCode] AS [ItemCode],
  [ItmDesc] AS [ItemDesc],
  [ItmLead] AS [LeadTime_Orginal],
  CASE WHEN ISNULL(ItmLead, '') ='' THEN 0 ELSE CHOOSE(ASCII(RIGHT(ItmLead, 1)), 0,1,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) * CAST(LEFT(ItmLead, LEN(ItmLead)-1) AS int) AS [LeadTimeInDays],
FROM dbo.nav_items;
```

**Any better solution would be very appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a solution, but it seems to be very ugly!

After using SQL ASCII on extra on last character it returned numbers 2 and 4 then I used CHOOSE to assing to those values numbers 1 and 7.

Having those allowed me to multiply it by first part of the field and achieve my objective.

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT
  [ItmCode] AS [ItemCode],
  [ItmDesc] AS [ItemDesc],
  [ItmLead] AS [LeadTime_Orginal],
  CASE WHEN ISNULL(ItmLead, '') ='' 
  THEN 0 
  ELSE CHOOSE(ASCII(RIGHT(ItmLead, 1)), 0,1,0,7,0,0) * CAST(LEFT(ItmLead, LEN(ItmLead)-1) AS int) AS [LeadTimeInDays],
FROM dbo.nav_items;
```

**Any better solution would be very appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I've seen others asking for help with this.

The code below will only work for formats with D, W, M or Y since I don't use C, WD or Q. Edit to match your database names.

Original code is taken from somewhere else on the internet.

Lead time date format is as following:

1 = C - Current (Last char can't end on this, and code below wont work for fields with this char)

2 = D - Day

3 = WD - WorkDay

4 = W - Week

5 = M - Month

6 = Q - Quarter

7 = Y - Year

In your select, do a case as following:

```
,   Case
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(2)  Then concat(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1),'D')
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(3)  Then concat(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1),'WD')
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(4)  Then concat(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1),'W')
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(5)  Then concat(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1),'M')
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(6)  Then concat(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1),'Q')
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(7)  Then concat(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1),'Y')
                                            End             as 'Vendor Lead Time'
,   Case
        When [Vendor Lead Time] is null             Then 0
        When [Vendor Lead Time] like ''             Then 0
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(2)  Then cast(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1)as int)
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(4)  Then cast(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1)*7 as int)
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(5)  Then cast(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1)*30 as int)
        When right([Vendor Lead Time],1) = char(7)  Then cast(left([Vendor Lead Time],len([Vendor Lead Time])-1)*365 as int)
                                            End             as  'Vendor Lead Time Days'
,   Case
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(2)    Then concat(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1),'D')
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(3)    Then concat(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1),'WD')
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(4)    Then concat(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1),'W')
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(5)    Then concat(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1),'M')
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(6)    Then concat(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1),'Q')
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(7)    Then concat(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1),'Y')
                                            End             as 'Vendor Transport Time'
,   Case
        When [Transport Time] is null               Then 0
        When [Transport Time] like ''               Then 0
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(2)    Then cast(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1)as int)
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(4)    Then cast(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1)*7 as int)
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(5)    Then cast(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1)*30 as int)
        When right([Transport Time],1) = char(7)    Then cast(left([Transport Time],len([Transport Time])-1)*365 as int)
                                            End             as 'Vendor Transport Time Days'
```

For total lead time, do a select for:

```
([Vendor Lead Time Days]+[Vendor Transport Time Days])  as 'Total Vendor Lead Time'
```